# MS Excel: Update table cell in another sheet based on formula result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Microsoft Excel 365. I have a spreadsheet for a sporting event where I have a sheet that is effectively a list of names and events entered.

In sheet 2, I have a box to set the event, and a FILTER function to get all competitors of that event and output them.

In sheet 2, I would like to have a position in the race as a user input, which will in-turn reference the points to be allocated (this is working). Where I'm getting stuck is then writing the resulting points allocation back in to the list of names in sheet 1.

I feel this will need to be done with VB, but what I'd like to have happen is identify when a cell is updated. The code will run which copies the value of that cell and then uses a FILTER in sheet 1 to update the original records correct column from the table.

Being unfamiliar with VB I'm getting stuck here and would appreciate some advice if anyone has any.

Comment: If the cell is updated manually, then look at using the `Worksheet.Change` event. If the cell contains a formula and its calculated value changes, look at the `Worksheet.Calculate` event.